# Drupal programmatically create node with workbench state published

Tags: drupal, workbench

I would like to programmatically create a node with the moderation state published, but it seems impossible. Does somebody know how to do it?

I also tried

```
$node->revision = 1;
$node->workbench_moderation_state_new = workbench_moderation_state_published();
node_save($node);
```

But the node still remains in draft.

Comment: Solution for this can be found here:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129491/change-workbench-state-from-draft-to-published-programatically

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$node = node_load($node->nid);
workbench_moderation_moderate($node, 'published');
```